# Determine the exact value of the ABCD square aspect

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> ABCD is a square measuring side $x$ cm.
>
> Let I be the point of [AB] such that AI = 10cm,
>
> J the point of [AD] such that AJ = 10cm,
>
> K the point of [DC] such that CK = 10cm
>
> and L the point of [BC] such that CL = 10cm
>
> The area of ​​quadrant IJKL is 1 square meter
>
> Question: Determine the exact value of the ABCD square aspect

My diagram:
[image]

Comment: OK, what have you tried? Did you draw a diagram?

Comment: https://www.ilemaths.net/img/forum_img/0052/forum_52933_1.gif                                                    the diagram

Comment: Please also define the 'square aspect' and, given your tag is 'contest math' please also give credit to where this problem originated

Answer (score 1):

Note that the square is the sum of the rectangle of area 100$^2$cm$^2$, a square of side 10 and a square of side $x-10$ So, by matching the total area of the square, the following equation can be established

$$x^2 = 100^2 + 10^2 + (x-10)^2$$

which yields $x$ = 510cm.

Comment: The area of the inscribed rectangle is 1 sq. meter, and it is inscribed into a rectangle that is only about 1/2 a meter on its side.  Really?

Comment: @Narlin - It is not half meter. It is about 5m.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a problem with being American!